# How to pull a git repository from remote server?

Tags: git

I've seen a few similar questions asked, but they didn't help me figure this out, and I couldn't find any tutorials (I wasn't really sure what I am looking for, to be honest). Also, I haven't used git apart from pulling/pushing onto GitHub, which is why (at least I believe so) I am so confused! GitHub made me spoiled about setting a repo up!

#### What I did on the server:

- `sudo apt-get install git` Which installed (I think) everything I needed to proceed.
- I created a test repository (just a few txt and html files) inside `git_test`
- `git init`
- `git add .`
- `git commit`
- I also used `vim .git/description` to change the description to `starships`.

#### What I did from my computer

*I have git pre-installed*

- `git clone destielstarship@`*`[remote_server]`*`/starships`<sup>1</sup>

Which produced this error: `fatal: Unable to look up destielstarship@`*`[remote_server]`*`(port 9418) (A non-recoverable error occurred during a database look-up. )`

---

1. I replaced the IP address with [remote_server] for clarity, I hope I didn't make it more confusing.

---

Update: Whoops! Fixed an awkward typo!

Comment: There's probably more than one reason this isn't working, but it's worth noting that your remote repository name for clone operations is going to be based on the directory name, not the git description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR

Unless you're running *git-daemon* on the remote server, you probably want to use ssh rather than git for your [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

### SSH Schemes

To use SSH as your transport, you can clone your repository using the a different URI scheme. For example, assuming your username on the remote host is "destielstarship," you could use the following command:

```
git clone ssh://destielstarship@remotehost.example.com/path/to/git_test
```

You can leave off the .git extension for the repository in most cases, and only need to specify a username for the remote host if it differs from your current login.

Comment: Oh, I *almost* got it to work! :D Now I got a `Permission Denied (publickey)` error. :/ I'll try to Google it!

Comment: @destielstarship That's a different question, but the most likely explanation is that you don't have your public key properly installed for destielstarship on the remote server, or you don't have your key loaded into your local ssh-agent.

Comment: I fixed the error I was having with the encryption. :D Thanks!